# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index, Could you please guys help me to know what is the problem?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have done this code for model updating, something that's related to civil engineering. In the very last line of the code provided I am getting this error (TyperError: only integer scalar .....), could you please tell me what is the problem? I've tried a lot, but not working. I've tried to convert it to an array with integer, float, and also convert it to list, but nothing is wokring
Thank you in advance

```
def objective_function(mac_s, F_s):
    return mac_s + F_s
empty_particle = {
    'Position': None,
    'Velocity': None,
    'J': None,
    'best-Position': None,
    'best-J': None
}
#1st block
for i in range(N_pop):
    particle.append(empty_particle.copy())
    particle[i]['Position'] = np.random.uniform(Varmin, Varmax, nvar)
    array_1 = np.array(particle[i]['Position'])
    #2nd block
    with open('Input_In.py', 'w') as f:
        content_1 = '{}( "{}" )\n'.format(a_text, b_text)
        f.write(content_1)
        for x in range(len(Parameters)):
            for j in range(len(Com)):
                if a < len(array_1):

                    content = '{}( "{}", "{}", "{}", {} )\n'.format(c_text, d_text, Com[j], Parameters[x], array_1[a])
                    f.write(content)
                    a += 1
        f.close()

    # 3rd block
    with open('Input_In.py', 'a+') as file_handle:
        file_handle.seek(0)
        data = file_handle.read(100)
        tenth_line = '{}( [ "{}" ] )\n'.format(r_text, k_text)
        file_handle.write(tenth_line)
        eleventh_line = '{}( "RESULT" )\n'.format(s_text)
        file_handle.write(eleventh_line)
        twel_line = '{}(  )\n'.format(w_test)
        file_handle.write(twel_line)
        thir_line = '{}'.format(z_test)
        file_handle.write(thir_line)
        file_handle.close()

    particle[i]['Velocity'] = np.zeros(nvar)
    f_out = 'Model_Updating.tb'
    _fileOne = open(f_in, 'r')
    f = open(f_out, 'w')

    counter = 0

    for line in fileinput.input([f_in]):
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter not in [67, 68, 69, 133, 134, 135, 199, 200, 201, 265, 266, 267, 331, 332, 333, 397, 398, 399, 463,
                           464, 465, 529, 530, 531, 595, 596, 597, 661, 662, 663, 727, 728, 729, 793, 794, 795, 859,
                           860, 861, 925, 926, 927]:
            f.write(line)
    f.close()

    eig = []
    eigen_vector = []
    frequency = []
    try:
        fn = open(f_out, 'r')
    except:
        print('Could not read the file')

    ln = fn.readline()
    lncnt = 1
    sensors, pos = [], []

    lst = []

    while ln:
        ln = fn.readline()

        if 'Mode nr.' in ln.strip():
            freq = float(fn.readline().split()[2])
            frequency.append(freq)
            new_list = []
            for u in sensor_node_num:
                if u not in new_list:
                    new_list.append(u)
            RANGE = 4 + len(new_list)
            head = [next(fn) for x in range(RANGE)]
            df = np.array([i.split() for i in head[4:int(RANGE)]], dtype=float)
            df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=head[3].split())
            for sensor, p in zip(sensor_node_num, position):
                o = df[df['Nodnr'] == sensor]
                if p == 'DtX':
                    eig = o.iat[0, 1]
                    lst.append(eig)
                elif p == 'DtY':
                    eig = o.iat[0, 2]
                    lst.append(eig)
                elif p == 'DtZ':
                    eig = o.iat[0, 3]
                    lst.append(eig)
                else:
                    print('Error')

    division = float(len(lst) / len(sensor_node_num))
    lst = np.array(lst)
    lst = np.array_split(lst, int(division))
    Operation = lst
    ev = pd.DataFrame(lst).T
    J = len(lst)
    freq_lst = np.array(frequency)
    freq_lst = np.array_split(freq_lst, J)
    fq = pd.DataFrame(freq_lst).T
    Exp_freq = np.array(Exp_freq)

    Y = eigen_vector_exp
    eigen_vector_exp = np.transpose(np.array(eigen_vector_exp))
    Numerical = np.transpose(np.array(lst))
    ed = pd.DataFrame(Numerical)
    pd = pd.DataFrame(eigen_vector_exp)
    mac_matrix_1 = np.zeros((eigen_vector_exp.shape[1], Numerical.shape[1]))
    MAC_n_e = np.zeros((Numerical.shape[1], eigen_vector_exp.shape[1]))
    Correl = np.zeros((Numerical.shape[1], eigen_vector_exp.shape[1]))

    ## Modal Coupling Problem

    for ii in range(len(ed.columns)):
        for k in range(len(pd.columns)):
            MAC_n_e[ii, k] = ((ed[ii].dot(Y[k])) ** 2) / ((ed[ii].dot(Operation[ii])) * (pd[k].dot(Y[k])))
            Correl[ii, k] = np.sqrt(np.abs((1 - MAC_n_e[ii, k]) / MAC_n_e[ii, k])) + np.sqrt(
                np.abs((Exp_freq[k] - freq_lst[ii]) / freq_lst[ii]))

    A = np.argmin(Correl, axis=0)

    FREQUENCY = []
    EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL = []

    for jj in A:
        alfa = freq_lst[jj]
        Beta = lst[jj]
        FREQUENCY.append(alfa)
        EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL.append(Beta)

    EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL = np.transpose(np.array(EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL))

    MAC_MATRIX = np.zeros((eigen_vector_exp.shape[1], EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL.shape[1]))

    for ii in range(eigen_vector_exp.shape[1]):
        for jj in range(EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL.shape[1]):
            MAC_MATRIX[ii, jj] = (np.dot(eigen_vector_exp[:, ii].T, EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL[:, jj]) ** 2) / np.dot(
                np.dot(EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL[:, jj].T, EIGEN_VECTOR_NUMERICAL[:, jj]),
                np.dot(eigen_vector_exp[:, ii], eigen_vector_exp[:, ii]))

    DIAG = np.diag(MAC_MATRIX)

    subs = 0
    for i in DIAG:
        AAA = 1 - i
        subs += AAA
    subs_1 = 0
    for i, j in zip(FREQUENCY, Exp_freq):
        PP = np.abs((i - j) / j)
        subs_1 += PP
    ## Modal Coupling Problem
    # 5th block
    particle[i]['J']= objective_function(mac_s=subs, F_s=subs_1)
```

Comment: what is the 'i' you're trying to use as an index for 'particle' which I assume is a list?

Comment: A polite thing to do when asking about an error is to show the full error with traceback.  That makes it easier to identify where the error occurred, and what variable(s) might be the problem.  Otherwise we have search through the code looking a suspicious indexing operation.  You are lucky to have a respondent that was willing to do that work!.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your advice, it is kind of you

Comment: @yanziselman yes it will be a list, i have made a mistake when considering "i" more than one time 
Anyway thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you start your loop by defining a running variable 'i'.
But all over the loop, you redefine it to be other integers and unrelated objects. Such as in line 83, line 155, and others.
It's difficult to understand your intentions from the question. but if I understand correctly, the problem can be solved by changing every 'i' in the loop to a differently named temporary variable.
A simpler solution would be to change the 'i' variable at the beginning of the for loop to smth else.
I suggest you adopt a habit of using variable names that have meaning and not just single or double letters.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, I needed to change the variable "i" into different definitions. Again thank you